# Ionic 2: Unable to navigate from inner function

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to navigate to a page , upon clicking on a google map marker. I'm able to do it outside the inner function (Inside initializeMap function only), just having problems doing it in a inner function.

This is my constructor:

```
static get parameters() {
    return [[NavController],[Platform]];
  }

  constructor(navController, platform, app) {
    this.navController = navController;
    this.platform = platform;
    this.app = app;

    this.map = null;
    this.markers = [];

   platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.initializeMap();
   });
  }
```

Inside my initializeMap method contains the populateLocks method:

```
function populateLocks(auth,unauth,map){

for (var k in auth) {
    (function (id) {
       var auth = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: authImage,
             map: map,
             position: authLocks[id].latLng
        });
       google.maps.event.addListener(auth, 'click', function () {
         //alert(auth[id].id);
         this.navController.push(SettingsPage);
          });
     })
     (k)
  }
```

Using this.navController or navController throws me error like:

for this.navController.push

[image]

for navController.push

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `() =>` instead of `function ()`

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

or use `var self = this;` outside the function and refer to `self.navController` instead of `this.navController` like so:

```
var self = this;
google.maps.event.addListener(auth, 'click', function () {
   //alert(auth[id].id);
   self.navController.push(SettingsPage);
});
```